# Xfce tap to click debian9

Tags: debian, xfce

I installed Debian 9, alongside with xfce.

My touchpad doesn't have a setting for tap to click.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is outlined in the bottom, just read it carefully.
Mine was:

```
xfconf-query -c pointers -p /ETPS2_Elantech_Touchpad/Properties/libinput_Tapping_Enabled -n -t int -s 1
```

https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/mouse